# Returning error from SQL Server SP called from MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure to delete a project. Projects have many relationships. Results in 9 delete statements. If any one fails (though they shouldn't...) I want to return an error to the caller (a MS Access vba program) and rollback the transaction.

I think I'm pretty close...can someone push me over the line?

```
    create procedure dbo.cpas_DeleteProject
@ProjectID INt = 0
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM tblWOTasks WHERE tblWOTasks.WorkOrderID IN (SELECT ID FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID)
        DELETE FROM tblELaborSpread WHERE tblELaborSpread.WorkOrderID IN (SELECT ID FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID)
        DELETE FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE tblWorkOrders.ProjectID IN (SELECT ID FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID)
        DELETE FROM tblCPTransactiON WHERE tblCPTransactiON.CPProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM tblCPJE WHERE tblcpje.jeid IN 
            (SELECT tblcpje.JEID FROM tblCPJE left joIN tblCPTransactiON as CR ON CR.CPTransID = tblCPJE.JECreditID 
                            left joIN tblCPTransactiON as DR ON DR.CPTransID = tblCPJE.JEDebitID 
                    WHERE DR.CPTransID is null AND cr.CPTransID is null)        
        DELETE FROM tblProjectTasks WHERE tblProjectTasks.ProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM xrefProjectMICAP WHERE xrefProjectMICAP.ProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM tblworkorders WHERE tblWorkOrders.ProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM tblprojects WHERE tblProjects.ID=@ProjectID
        --Project Comments cascade delete....
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
             {somewhere here I need to post an error message so Access will see it...}
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the proper way of doing this, but here is just my suggestion.  Can you add ***SELECT 0 As ErrorCode*** after the commit transaction and ***SELECT 1 As ErrorCode*** after the rollback transaction?

The only time you will get the 1 back is when something actually fail and that it goes to the CATCH block.  On your VBA process you can return the recordset back and check for the rs("ErrorCode").  If it is not zero (0), you know you something went wrong and that it fell to the CATCH block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an output parameter (for example `@errorFlag`) setting it to 1 only when an error occurs and leaving it set to 0 otherwise:

```sql
create procedure dbo.cpas_DeleteProject
@ProjectID INt = 0,
@errorFlag int OUTPUT
AS
set @errorFlag=0
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM tblWOTasks WHERE tblWOTasks.WorkOrderID IN (SELECT ID FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID)
        DELETE FROM tblELaborSpread WHERE tblELaborSpread.WorkOrderID IN (SELECT ID FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID)
        DELETE FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE tblWorkOrders.ProjectID IN (SELECT ID FROM tblWorkOrders WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID)
        DELETE FROM tblCPTransactiON WHERE tblCPTransactiON.CPProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM tblCPJE WHERE tblcpje.jeid IN 
            (SELECT tblcpje.JEID FROM tblCPJE left joIN tblCPTransactiON as CR ON CR.CPTransID = tblCPJE.JECreditID 
                            left joIN tblCPTransactiON as DR ON DR.CPTransID = tblCPJE.JEDebitID 
                    WHERE DR.CPTransID is null AND cr.CPTransID is null)        
        DELETE FROM tblProjectTasks WHERE tblProjectTasks.ProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM xrefProjectMICAP WHERE xrefProjectMICAP.ProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM tblworkorders WHERE tblWorkOrders.ProjectID=@ProjectID
        DELETE FROM tblprojects WHERE tblProjects.ID=@ProjectID
        --Project Comments cascade delete....
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    set @errorFlag=1
END CATCH
```

Comment: Will the sql as written accomplish the commit/rollback objective?

Comment: @JimS-Indy The logic of your procedure hasn't been changed: my answer only adds an output parameter to inform SP caller that something went wrong. So if the SP accomplished the commit/rollback objective in your original version, it will accomplish it even with the addition of an output parameter, but I think that the only way to be sure it works is to try it.